# *Increased* Verb or adjective

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

Can we use the word *increased* as an adjective?

I have found that in many sentences word *increased* is used as both "has increased" and "is increased", as in these:

> Water level **is increased** by 1%.
>   Water level **has increased** by 1%.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I don't know I am asking also about the same question howevere I don't know if the first sentence is correct or not

Answer (score 2):

In your examples, *increased* is not really an adjective but part of the verb.

It's best to think of English verbs as able to have forms that are composed of two or three words (i.e. the entire phrase is the verb), versus other languages that use a common stem with different endings or other schemes.

All English verbs have a "past participle" form, that is used in constructs with *to be* and *to have* to express different tenses, aspects, etc.  Think of *has increased* as being a different tense ([past perfect](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastperfect.html)) of the verb *to increase*, and likewise with *is increased* ([passive present](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/activepassive.html)).

But your first sentence is fine.  It's common to use passive present to describe something that has happened "on its own" with no person or definite subject causing it.

Comment: I don't know why, but when I read "water level is increased 1%" I expect there to be some further explanation: "...when the thing catalyzes the other thing" -- it sounds quite odd standing on its own.

Answer (score 0):

"Increased" can certainly be used as an adjective. Almost any quantifiable noun can be referred to as "increased". Post-911, "increased security" is a common term.

> increased security and surveillance could lessen the chances of
>   terrorist success.

J.J. Kramer, "The Role of Behavioral Science in Physical Security"

Likewise, in medicine one can speak of "increased bone density", "increased reflex time", "increased serum cholesterol", etc. and most physical sciences do the same. It is a very common construction.